# How to sort dependencies in teamcity

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to sort dependencies in teamcity by build number?

By default, some builds go to the end and are very hard to find.

[image: an example of the wrong sorting in team city]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on TeamCity Issues Tracker and they said it will be fixed in version 2020.1

P.S i 've used your image as reference.

[How to sort dependencies in teamcity - YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-64703)